# paper-dropdown-menu options are horizontally stacked instead of vertically stacked

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

In the Polymer labs todo-list https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list.git, i added a paper-dropdown menu like so in index.html

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
<span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">

<todo-auth id="auth"
           user="{{user}}"
           location="[[firebaseURL]]"
           user="{{user}}">
</todo-auth>

<todo-data location="[[firebaseURL]]"
           todos="{{todos}}"
           user="{{user}}">
</todo-data>

<todo-view class="flex"
           route="{{route}}"
           todos="{{todos}}"
           on-sign-out="signOut">
</todo-view>

<paper-dropdown-menu label="Time">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
    <paper-item>All dDay</paper-item>
    <paper-item>AM</paper-item>
    <paper-item>PM</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>

<paper-toast id="caching-complete"
             duration="6000"
             text="Caching complete! This app will work offline.">
</paper-toast>
```

However, instead of the options being vertically stacked, they are being stacked horizontally like so[image]

In the source code for the paper-dropdown-menu demo, I do not see them doing anything special to have it vertically stacked. May i know what is overriding the default styling in the todo-list app and how to get it to be vertically stacked? Thanks.

Comment: Did you import `paper-dropdown-menu`, `paper-listbox` like [this](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list/blob/master/app/elements/elements.html#L15) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the `paper-dropdown-menu`, `paper-listbox` before using it. Make sure that `paper-dropdown-menu`, `paper-listbox` & `paper-item` are imported like [this](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list/blob/master/app/elements/elements.html#L15)

Here is a working demo of `paper-dropdown-menu` alone

```html
<html>  
<head>

  <title>Template me</title>
  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">

<custom-listbox id="CustomListboxID"></custom-listbox>

<dom-module is="custom-listbox">
<template>
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Time">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
    <paper-item>All dDay</paper-item>
    <paper-item>AM</paper-item>
    <paper-item>PM</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>

</template>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'custom-listbox'
});
</script>

</dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure that I imported those. Problem was between keyboard and chair. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I'd imported everything but paper-item. Was scratching my head and it was so obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are missing the `paper-menu` part. The below excerpt is from the docs.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
<paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
<paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
<paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
<paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```